# How to dynamically load video,pdf,ppf files in ionic content ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic3

I am new to ionic, Now in my project i have one screen which will load all the images,videos,ppt,pdf from databsae.

My json will be :

```
"FileSource":"http://www.example.com/assets/designs/images/new_banner2.jpg",
 "FileSource": "http://www.example.com/assets/designs/images/small.3gp",
 "FileSource": "http://www.example.com/assets/designs/images/Biology in a changing world.pptx",
"FileSource": "http://www.example.com/assets/designs/images/preface.pdf",
```

SO my `FileSource` will have all the image,ppt,pdf,video which is comming from database.

Now i want to show all the thing in grid view mannaer. I have tried and i can display the `FileSourceName`.But i dont know how can i populate the image,video,ppt,pdf..

Like its should be in grid view.I have done the grid view and at top it will display the what the file name is like :

```
<ion-content style="width: 100%;overflow-y: hidden;">


<div class="item item-body no-padding" style="border-width: 0px !important;">  

  <div class="row no-padding" *ngFor="let data of Catdata; let i = index">

          <div class="col col-50 custom-design2" style="background: url(background image ) no-repeat center;background-size: cover;">
               <div class="custom-design1"><span class="grid-title">{{Catdata[i].FileName}}</span></div>
            </div>
</div> 


</ion-content>
```

Now my grid view is like :

```
Image


video


ppt

pdf
```

the above is like grid view and it will have the title. But i dont jnow dynamically how can i populate the image,video,ppt,pdf in my grid view. and i need to show all the image,ppt,video,pdf in pop up screen with cross cancel button at right corner.when user press any grid view cell.

Please help me out..how can i do this ??